# If the host directory is a link, G-WAN does not find that listener

Tags: listener, symlink, g-wan

Has anyone had the same experience? If the host directory is a link to another directory, gwan can't open that listener.

For example, if `0.0.0.0_8080` is a symbolic link to another directory, then `gwan` does not to open that listener.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm. This has been investigated and fixed, thank you to your report!

The cause of the symbolic links exclusion was coming from a test that excluded all attributes but `directory flags`.

Another user reported that listeners defined on a volume using the `XFS file system` were also ignored. This has been fixed too and will be released in G-WAN v3.10+.